# NPM install after installing OS X El Capitan

Tags: node.js, osx-elcapitan

I’m trying to run npm install, in order to install dependencies of my project, this was working before I installed El Capitan (on Mac).

I tried reinstalling node and npm through the following :

1.node js installer package

2.nvm

3.homebrew

npm -v
2.14.4

node -v
v4.1.1

```
> bufferutil@1.1.0 install /Users/adamkraif/Documents/workspace/hunter-asteroid/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                        ^
../../nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:672:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t'
      (aka 'unsigned int') to 'enum encoding' for 3rd argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:
      candidate function not viable: 2nd argument ('const char *') would lose
      const qualifier
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note:
      candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note:
      candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:676:12: error: no viable conversion from
      'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate
      constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'const
      v8::Local<v8::Object> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate
      constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object> &&'
      for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:214:13: note: candidate
      template ignored: could not match 'Local' against 'MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: candidate
      template ignored: could not match 'S *' against
      'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>'
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
../../nan/nan.h:683:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to
      'v8::Primitive *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from
      macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:414:12: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Primitive>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to
      'v8::Boolean *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from
      macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:424:12: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Boolean>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::True(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to
      'v8::Function *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from
      macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1514:12: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Function>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(handle)->Get(kCallbackIndex)
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:7:
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:221:5: error: assigning to
      'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Value *'
    TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/adamkraif/.node-gyp/4.1.1/include/node/v8.h:180:37: note: expanded from
      macro 'TYPE_CHECK'
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:1632:12: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'v8::Local<v8::Object>::Local<v8::Value>' requested here
    return NanEscapeScope(handle->Get(NanNew(key)).As<v8::Object>());
           ^
../../nan/nan.h:398:30: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                             ^
9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/adamkraif/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/adamkraif/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/adamkraif/Documents/workspace/hunter-asteroid/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok

npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON hunterasteroid@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON hunterasteroid@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON hunterasteroid@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/adamkraif/.node/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.1.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamkraif/Documents/workspace/hunter-asteroid/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like contextify doesn't work on Node versions 4.x at the moment, due to this issue:
https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/180

You could downgrade to 0.12.7 by using n, like this:
npm install -g n &&
n 0.12.7

Then this should work, and you should be able to install your deps:
npm install -g contextify

Comment: I successfully downgraded using brew. `brew tap homebrew/versions;
brew install homebrew/versions/node012`

Answer (score 2):

I found that it's usually because one of the dependencies is not compatible with node 4.1.1 
Usually I use npm-check-update ([ncu](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates)) to see if there are latest versions of the dependencies, if so, I update to the latest and try. Usually it works because the module author has fixed it (especially if it's a popular module)

Install:
`npm install npm-check-updates -g`

Run:
`ncu`

If you see newer modules, run:

`ncu -u`

Note: This updates all the packages to their latest modules. There is also command to update only the ones you need.